# How to mount an smb share with `rwx` permission for all using `mount` command?

Tags: macos, network, permission, sharing, smb

I am trying to mount two network smb shares so that all clients/users have `rwx` access. Network shares are on a Mac mini. Accessing from an iMac. Two shares are `smb://192.168.5.1/PlexMedia_2` and `smb://192.168.5.1/PlexMedia_1`

When using the `mv` command from iMac I can copy files from `/Volumes/PlexMedia_1` to `/Volumes/PlexMedia_2` without issue. When using FileBot.app to rename/move a file between those same two drives it fails because of a permissions issue. The smb shares are mounted with `rwx` permissions for john. When I have meddled with permissions on the server they have mounted with `rwx` for all users and still FileBot.app fails to move files due to permissions error.

current permissions on the client/iMac:

```
at iMacEth ~ ls -ale /Volumes/PlexMedia_2 
total 224
drwx------@  1 john  staff  16384 Oct 25 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel    320 Oct 26 18:15 ..
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 17 02:11 Series
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 26 17:27 pTemp

at iMacEth ~ ls -ale /Volumes/PlexMedia_1 
total 384
drwx------@  1 john  staff  16384 Oct 25 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel    320 Oct 26 18:15 ..
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 16 22:35 Movies
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Mar  8  2023 Movies_B
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 May  2 14:07 Music
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 May 17 16:45 Unsorted
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Apr  8  2023 WebTools-NG
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 26 17:27 pTemp
```

current permissions on the server/Mac mini:

```
john@Mac-mini ~ % ls -ale /Volumes/PlexMedia_1 
total 64
drwxrwxrwx@   15 john  staff     578 Oct 25 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x     9 root  wheel     288 Oct 26 15:04 ..
drwxrwxrwx  7248 john  staff  246432 Oct 16 22:35 Movies
drwxrwxrwx     5 john  staff     170 Mar  8  2023 Movies_B
drwxrwxrwx     3 john  staff     102 May  2 14:07 Music
drwxrwxrwx     3 john  staff     102 May 17 16:45 Unsorted
drwxrwxrwx     4 john  staff     136 Apr  8  2023 WebTools-NG
drwxrwxrwx     6 john  staff     204 Oct 26 15:21 pTemp

john@Mac-mini ~ % ls -ale /Volumes/PlexMedia_2 
total 32
drwxrwxrwx@  11 john  staff    442 Oct 25 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x    9 root  wheel    288 Oct 26 15:04 ..
drwxrwxrwx  153 john  staff   5202 Oct 17 02:11 Series
drwxrwxrwx    5 john  staff    170 Oct 26 15:21 pTemp
```

Been looking into mounting smb shares with the `mount` command and not having any luck. Fails whether I use `user:password@` or just `user@` and I'd rather not have commands with my password in history, etc.

```
at iMacEth ~ mount -v -t smbfs -o nosuid,-d=777 //john@192.168.5.1  ./
Password for 192.168.5.1: 
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
mount: /Users/john failed with 77
```

I changed mask settings on the server for the SharePoints using Directory Utility.app

I changed:

`dsAttrTypeNative:smb_createmask` to `777` from `644`
`dsAttrTypeNative:smb_directorymask` to `777` from `755`

For both volumes... made no difference. Like I said above. Here are the permissions now with those volumes mounted by the iMac/client:

```
at iMacEth ~ ls -ale /Volumes/PlexMedia_1 
total 384
drwxrwxrwx@  1 john  staff  16384 Oct 25 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel    320 Oct 26 19:45 ..
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 16 22:35 Movies
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Mar  8  2023 Movies_B
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 May  2 14:07 Music
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 May 17 16:45 Unsorted
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Apr  8  2023 WebTools-NG
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 26 19:19 pTemp

at iMacEth ~ ls -ale /Volumes/PlexMedia_2 
total 224
drwxrwxrwx@  1 john  staff  16384 Oct 25 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel    320 Oct 26 19:45 ..
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 26 19:24 .fseventsd
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 17 02:11 Series
drwxrwxrwx   1 john  staff  16384 Oct 26 19:19 pTemp

at iMacEth ~ ls -l@ /Volumes/           
drwxrwxrwx@  1 john  staff  16384 Oct 25 22:05 PlexMedia_1
    com.apple.provenance       11 
drwxrwxrwx@  1 john  staff  16384 Oct 25 22:05 PlexMedia_2
    com.apple.provenance       11
```

Are there some ACLs or something else I need to set on the server to allow these shares to mount without restrictions... I've looked and can't nail it down. One week now meddling with this.

It appears `com.apple.provenance` is an empty extended attribute:

```
at iMacEth ~ xattr -p com.apple.provenance /Volumes/PlexMedia_1

at iMacEth ~ xattr -p com.apple.provenance /Volumes/PlexMedia_2
```

A little more research led me to this [Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201684) on umask.

Looking in the directory it mentions this folder:

```
00:24:31.999 at iMacEth ~ tree -L 1 /private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd 
/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd
├── config
├── disabled.501.plist
└── disabled.plist
```

I am wondering why many applications are in the **disabled. plist**?

Thanks for any input!